# How to get the corresponding id data from mysql in the modal?

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have different image button in my website and different modal will display after click the image. I have assigned different id to image button. I want to get the corresponding id data from mysql into modal content. But how can I pass the value of jquery to php?

I created a variable to store the id of imagebutton. But I don't know how to pass the value to php and use it to get data from my sql.

// Main page of imagebutton//

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-4">
<a class="btn btn-primary pull-right playerbutton" data-toggle="modal" 
href="#" id="5"><img src="images\123.png" class="squadplayerimg"></a>
<div class="modal-container"></div>
</div>
```

// External modal//

```
<!--  player Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal5" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="modal5" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
```

//jquery script//

```
$('a.playerbutton').click(function(event) {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
    var url = "modal.php?id=" + status;
    alert(url);
    $('.modal-container').load(url,function(result){
        $('#modal' + status).modal({show:true});
    );
});
```

I want to use the id in url to get corresponding data from mysql. But I dont't know how to pass the value to php. Thanks for you help.

//php//

```
<?php include 'login.php';
$id = $_GET["id"];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM player
WHERE id = "$id";";
$res=$mysqli->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo "id: " . $row["ID"]. " - Name: " . $row["Name"].  "<br>";}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}
$mysqli->close();
?>


<!--  player Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal+$id" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria- 
labelledby="modal+$id" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<!--  Content of modal -->
```

Comment: You seem to have passed the number from jQuery already. What does your php look like and what is the exact problem?

Comment: Hello jeroen Thanks for answering. I wonder  var url = "modal.php?id=" + status; is correct or not, because I get nothing from response. If I use var url = "modal.php"; I can get modal back.

Comment: Hello Dharman, thanks for answering my question, I am struggling how to pass id value in jquery to php to get data from mysql. Is there any method to perform this operation? Thanks

Comment: What about Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want data to render in modal that is stored in your SQL database. Essentially you cannot render PHP in Javascript easily without cause some vunderabilites to your code.

The better approach is if you set-up a seperated PHP file that can accept the data and then redener this into your elements respectively

You would probably want something like this in your severside php file.

```
`<?php
///This is to protect the various API methods
   error_reporting(0);
   $method = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
   switch ($method) {
   case 'PUT':
      header("Location: https://yoururl");   
     break;
   case 'POST':
      $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
      header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
      http_response_code (200);
      echo json_encode($json);
      break;
  case 'GET':
     header("Location: https://yoururl"); 
     break;
  default:
     header("Location: https://yoururl");  
     break;
 }

fucnction RetrieveDataFromServer($data){
/// Do something to get your data
return $data;
}
```

Then you will need to set-up your ajax query like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type:'post',
    url:'url for your php file',
    contentType: 'applicaition/json',
    data: data /// (could  be form data or data required like the id),
    success: function (data){
     //Inspect the data and then append to your html elements
    },
    error: function(x,e){
       console.log(e) ///This is so you can inspect the console and find our the errors you are facing in posting the data
    if (x.status==0) {
            console.log('You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.');
        } else if(x.status==404) {
            console.log('Requested URL not found.');
        } else if(x.status==500) {
            console.log('Internel Server Error.');
        } else if(e=='parsererror') {
            console.log('Error.\nParsing JSON Request failed.');
        } else if(e=='timeout'){
            console.log('Request Time out.');
        } else {
            console.log('Unknow Error.\n'+x.responseText);
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this is helpful, and hope i have answered your question.

NOTE: Remember this is asynchronus and you may need think about the timings with your server calls and rendering it on the page.

Just add a comment if i have missed anything and i can update the answer where required.